# UIButton touch up inside not calling IBAction on some devices

Tags: ios, swift, uiaccessibility

I have a 1x1 point UIButton that I'm using like a skip link for accessibility purposes. When VoiceOver is on and the user douple tap on the button to do some action, the associated IBAction is not called. This only happens on iPad 10.5" (I have not tried it on 12" yet). It works fine on iPhones and iPad Air and iPad Air 2.

What could be the possible reason for this behavior?

Comment: I specifically said I double tap when VoiceOver is on. That is the only way to access the button. It is 1x1 point.

Comment: Why can't this button be 10X10 or more ?

Comment: It's comparable to web's skip link - something that is not visible or accessible to regular user, to prevent them tapping on it by mistake.

Comment: so for this purpose you can use gesture recognizer with say two finger double tap, this is also rare for any regular user, unless specified.

Comment: @Rizwan I'm not sure if you have used VoiceOver before, but a double tap when VoiceOver is on invokes touch up inside, so I don't see how a gesture recognizer would help in this case? Can you explain more?

Comment: @Rizwan Actually when VoiceOver is on, you have to tap 2 times to activate the selected item.

Comment: @matchifang - No I havn't used it. I am in impression that you need a hidden event for some purpose to designated users only. Sorry for creating confusion.

Comment: @matchifang could you reproduce this in some isolated way? Like in separate app? Or on different view? Just to exclude particular view/view controller loading specifics.